# How to make my array index equal to position in android

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-listview

i am making music app. i am using listview. i made array of music files and put music in raw folder. i want to make my array index equal to listview position. if listview position is 6 then my array index should b 6. i am using onclick listener on image click of listview. i am trying that if listview position 5 button clicked then array index sound 5 play. for that i am using loop.

```
public void onClick(View v) {  
            TypedArray musicarry = context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.musicarry);
            int len= musicarry.length();
            int[] musiclength = new int[len];
            for (int i=0;i<musiclength.length;i++){

           }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use tags on your view. So when you are inflating your list view items then call method `setTag(position)` in your getView() method.

And in you onClick() method you can get the position using `v.getTag()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing onClick on your ListView, you should implement setOnItemClickListener on your adapter which also returns index of selected item.

Comment: OnItem click i have used but i have 2 images and 1 textview i only want to click imagview and give them functionality.